Accessing AWS Access Portal via Google App
I used the following document to use Google as my idP to AWS. I followed the instructions and apart from the final step (Step 7: Google Workspace: Confirm Google Workspace users access to AWS resources) all went well.
In the final step, it states:

Scroll to the bottom of the apps list where your custom Google
Workspace apps are located. Two apps are displayed Amazon Web Services
and AWS Access Portal

At no point in the instructions does it mention the AWS Access Portal app before this point. After following the instructions I only have the Amazon Web Services app which I cannot use to log in with. How does one setup the AWS Access Portal app in Google?
If I go directly to the Org AWS Access Portal link (https://d-abcdef.awsapps.com/start) I can log in fine using my Google credentials so SAML etc are all working fine and the uses have been imported into AWS okay.
